# JavaScript: передать cookie в запросе к php файлу

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, обязательно ли устанавливать в Ajax запросе  параметр `headers: {'Cookie': document.cookie }`, чтобы в `php` получить cookie браузера?

Например:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "file/cooc.php",
       headers: {
           'Cookie': document.cookie
        }

    })
    .done(function(msg) {
        $('#fn').html(msg);
    });
});
```

Я использую Chrome и без этого параметра проблем не возникает. Получается, что этот параметр лучше все равно использовать для, например, старых браузеров?

Comment: Какие старые браузеры? Даже IE6 куки слал на каждый запрос к серверу :)

Comment: @Visman, Тогда зачем эта опция?

Comment: Так в заголовках не только куки передавать можно.

Comment: @Visman, Например? Есть ведь параметр data куда можно записать любые данные.

Comment: Данные это данные (их обрабатывает ваш код php), а заголовки у вас может обрабатывать не только php, но и apache/nginx.

Comment: Ответ Нет.если нужно в PHP получить это значение то посылайте вместе с остальными параметрами.И уже в PHP обрабатывайте его под свои нужды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie — небольшой фрагмент данных, отправленный веб-сервером и хранимый на компьютере пользователя. Веб-клиент (обычно веб-браузер) всякий раз при попытке открыть страницу соответствующего сайта пересылает этот фрагмент данных веб-серверу в составе HTTP-запроса. Применяется для сохранения данных на стороне пользователя, на практике обычно используется для:

```
аутентификации пользователя;
хранения персональных предпочтений и настроек пользователя;
отслеживания состояния сеанса[en] доступа пользователя;
ведения статистики о пользователях.
```

То есть это часть `HTTP` заголовков которые автоматически передаются при любых типов `HTTP` запросов.

```
GET
POST
PUT
```

И не важно вы запрос сделали просто посетив страницу сайта (то есть простой гет запрос), или  ajax запрос.

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

Если вы явно не пытаетесь изменить какие то заголовки запроса то нет смысла передавать их явно.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "file/cooc.php"
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
        $('#fn').html(msg);
    });
});
```

Более подробно об этом можете прочитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie).